# how to enable TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV on apache

Tags: apache, security, ssl

I read on various forums regarding `POODLE` vulnerability in `SSLv3`. It is recommended to disable `SSLv3` and support `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV` on servers.

How to enable support of `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV` on `apache2.2`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of openssl, which [automatically supports TLS-FALLBACK-SCSV](https://twitter.com/RichSalz/status/522598645653594112). Apache will use that.

From https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20141015.txt :

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1 users should upgrade to 1.0.1j.
OpenSSL 1.0.0 users should upgrade to 1.0.0o.
OpenSSL 0.9.8 users should upgrade to 0.9.8zc.
```

Debian and other Distributions are deploying backports of the TLS-FALLBACK-SCSV update on OpenSSL.

**Restart your Apache after the update.**

### Check your server

[SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/) will check whether you support `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV`.

Notice how https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=google.com&s=74.125.239.96&hideResults=on notes "TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV supported"

Comment: Damn it, you beat me to it. You can also explicitly disable SSLv2/3 in the apache config, just for good measure.

Comment: Upgrading alone is not sufficient. You MUST disable SSLv2 and SSLv3. See answer below.

Comment: The question was 'How to enable support of TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV on apache2.2?' not 'How do I disable SSLv3?'

Comment: @tomf the question is how to protect myself from poodle. A complete answer is required not a dogmatic answer.

Comment: This does not fix the issue for me. Have OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, and have disabled SSLv2/3, but the "No, TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV not supported" message still appears. Ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your issue was addressed in http://serverfault.com/questions/658270/how-to-update-libssl-for-tls-fallback-scsv-vulnerability-on-nginx-configuration#comment801113_658270

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be necessary to do both; TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV is a mechanism to prevent downgrade attacks, but if your server does not allow SSLv3 (or v2) connections it is not needed (as those downgraded connections would not work)

Edit (to incorporate feedback):
Technically TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV is still useful with SSL disabled, because it helps avoid the connection being downgraded to TLS < 1.2. But this is unnecessary to defend against POODLE, since the vulnerable SSLv3 is off.

The only reason TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV is helpful against POODLE is if you need to support SSLv3 clients (really old IE versions or something). Those clients will still be vulnerable to the attack, but modern clients which support that option would be safe against the downgrade attack.

Comment: If you disable SSLv3, `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV` is not necessary to defend against POODLE. True. However, it is useful because it stops TLSv1.2 clients being downgraded to TLSv1 (which has no serious issues at the moment, but may do in the future).

Comment: Agreed, notice too how SSLlabs will agree here as well. On the google.com link in @tomf's answer, the status is "mitigated by server" on POODLE, not "vulnerable:no". In the philosophy of security, I can "mitigate" the chance of someone breaking in my front door with a lock or other prohibitive measures. Or, I can completely knock the door out and replace it with brick and mortar. Do both. See https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=safesurfing.ca for the difference when you do both.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire In this case though, disabling SSLv3 is like removing the front door entirely. There's not much sense in putting a padlock on a brick wall.

Comment: um, that's my point. Don't put a pad lock at all, get rid of it entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to the latest OpenSSL package that implements TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV. Then in your Apache configuration disable SSLv3 as well.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2  -SSLv3
```

This answer on the 'askubuntu' stack site goes into a lot more detail and has answers for how to configure a bunch of different servers for this.

> https://askubuntu.com/questions/537196/how-do-i-patch-workaround-sslv3-poodle-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, it's not a configuration in Apache but a behavior of openssl.

> OpenSSL has added support for TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV to allow applications
>   to block the ability for a MITM attacker to force a protocol
>   downgrade.

https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20141015.txt

On Debian, you can upgrade openssl without upgrading libssl, you really want libssl to be upgraded.  Apache uses libssl.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm is not need change nothing on Apache (at least for Ubuntu 14.04) I have restarted Apache after the update of openssl and `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV` is working.

Comment: You need to disable SSLv3 if you don't REALLY need it. Very little does need it.

Comment: @BillR That's not the question. Please try to answer only the question

Comment: They are asking about a security related question related to an existing and unpatched vulnerability. Stop being literal and more interested in a complete answer. This is not an unusual stance from others here who add to answers when the question asking may have missed other aspects of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following line in your configuration file, or replace any existing line starting with SSLProtocol:
`SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3`

Then run: `$ sudo apache2ctl configtest && sudo service apache2 restart`

You can **test** running command `$ openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -ssl3`

Answer (score 0):

TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV is the magic-word.
For more details, refer to [http://www.exploresecurity.com](http://www.exploresecurity.com/poodle-and-the-tls_fallback_scsv-remedy/), this is what it says:

> TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV is a fake cipher suite advertised in the Client
>   Hello, which starts the SSL/TLS handshake. SCSV stands for “Signaling
>   Cipher Suite Value”. The idea of using a cipher suite as a signal is
>   not new: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV is a way clients can
>   advertise that they support secure renegotiation (addressing
>   CVE-2009-3555)

So, finally, for a Spring-boot project with embedded Apache Server, configuration would show up something like this:

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSvx,TLSvx.y....
server.ssl.protocol=TLS
server.ssl.ciphers=TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_............TLS_EMPTY_RENAGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV 
server.server-header="Willi Wonka!"
```

**PS** - To see all the the Spring-boot configurations / properties, plese visit this: [https://docs.spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)