# How to Enable TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV support in Tomcat 8.5.x.Help me to get it Done

Tags: security, ssl, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat8.5

I am using Tomcat 8.5.91. When scanning with SSL Labs, it indicates that TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV is not supported, which may leave the server vulnerable to SSL downgrade attacks. Although my SSL/TLS connection test is successful, I want to address this issue by enabling TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV support in my Tomcat web server.

The SSL Labs scan results are as follows:

Offer SSLv2: No
Offer SSLv3: No
Offer TLS1.0: Yes
Offer TLS1.1: Yes
Offer TLS1.2: Yes

While I understand that TLS versions 1.0 and later inherently mitigate downgrade attacks, I am committed to implementing additional security measures, including enabling TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV. Therefore, I am seeking guidance on how to enable TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV support in Tomcat 8.5.91. Communities assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated.

Refered this article from stackoverflow : [how to enable TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV on apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406586/how-to-enable-tls-fallback-scsv-on-apache)

#tomcat #tomcatsecurity #ssl #tls

How to Enable TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV support in Tomcat 8.5.x.Help me to get it Done.

Comment: This is not a feature of Tomcat, but of the underlying Java version. Looks like this is not supported by Java because it is considered not needed - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8061798. Apart from that you might better invest your time into moving to a newer Tomcat version instead of chasing an irrelevant issue. Tomcat 8.5.x is end of life in about 3 month.

Comment: I am using OpenSSL 3.0.11 as the SSL Engine for the Tomcat with Tomcat Native APR as a Protocol for the Connector.So here the CRYPTO Engine is openssl so No java is involved.Your point is correct when I am using Default JSSE Implementation.